# Not able to download document which is having # in Document Name

Tags: sharepoint-online, development

I am having problem to downaload the document which contains # in document Name.
I am getting error "File Not Found."

I am trying this in sharepoint CSOM COde.Need help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use CSOM API with filename containing `#` or `%`, new methods must be used (with `Path` inside the name). Check this article from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/supporting-and-in-file-and-folder-with-the-resourcepath-api

For example, change:

```
 web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl
```

To:

```
web.GetFileByServerRelativePath
```

Comment: Thank you, It's working for me.